# RESOLVE Freemode of SwiperJS doesn't work for React TS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, swiper.js

I have a little problem with SwiperJS. I use the version 10.1.0 and I have this code :

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import "swiper/css";

export default function Discover() {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="m-0 mb-5 relative overflow-hidden bg-no-repeat bg-image-popular bg-cover font-sans">
                <div className="relative z-10">
                    <Swiper
                        spaceBetween={0}
                        slidesPerView={1}
                        loop={true}
                        freeMode={true}
                        className="mySwipper my-12"
                        pagination={{
                            clickable: true,
                        }}
                    >
                        <SwiperSlide className="w-full px-2">
                            <div className="h-fit w-auto overflow-hidden opacity-100 container mx-auto ">
                                <div className="-m-1 flex flex-wrap md:-m-2">
                                    <div className="flex w-1/2 flex-wrap">
                                        <div className="w-1/2 p-1 md:p-2">
                                            <img
                                                alt="gallery"
                                                className="block h-full w-full rounded-lg object-cover object-center"
                                                src="https://tecdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(70).webp"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="w-1/2 p-1 md:p-2">
                                            <img
                                                alt="gallery"
                                                className="block h-full w-full rounded-lg object-cover object-center"
                                                src="https://tecdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(72).webp"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="w-full p-1 md:p-2">
                                            <img
                                                alt="gallery"
                                                className="block h-full w-full rounded-lg object-cover object-center"
                                                src="https://tecdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(73).webp"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="flex w-1/2 flex-wrap">
                                        <div className="w-full p-1 md:p-2">
                                            <img
                                                alt="gallery"
                                                className="block h-full w-full rounded-lg object-cover object-center"
                                                src="https://tecdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(74).webp"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="w-1/2 p-1 md:p-2">
                                            <img
                                                alt="gallery"
                                                className="block h-full w-full rounded-lg object-cover object-center"
                                                src="https://tecdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(75).webp"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="w-1/2 p-1 md:p-2">
                                            <img
                                                alt="gallery"
                                                className="block h-full w-full rounded-lg object-cover object-center"
                                                src="https://tecdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(77).webp"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </SwiperSlide>
                        <SwiperSlide className="w-full px-2">
                            <div className="h-fit w-auto overflow-hidden opacity-100 container mx-auto ">
                                <div className="-m-1 flex flex-wrap md:-m-2">
                                    <div className="flex w-1/2 flex-wrap">
                                        <div className="w-1/2 p-1 md:p-2">
                                            <img
                                                alt="gallery"
                                                className="block h-full w-full rounded-lg object-cover object-center"
                                                src="https://tecdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(70).webp"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="w-1/2 p-1 md:p-2">
                                            <img
                                                alt="gallery"
                                                className="block h-full w-full rounded-lg object-cover object-center"
                                                src="https://tecdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(72).webp"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="w-full p-1 md:p-2">
                                            <img
                                                alt="gallery"
                                                className="block h-full w-full rounded-lg object-cover object-center"
                                                src="https://tecdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(73).webp"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="flex w-1/2 flex-wrap">
                                        <div className="w-full p-1 md:p-2">
                                            <img
                                                alt="gallery"
                                                className="block h-full w-full rounded-lg object-cover object-center"
                                                src="https://tecdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(74).webp"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="w-1/2 p-1 md:p-2">
                                            <img
                                                alt="gallery"
                                                className="block h-full w-full rounded-lg object-cover object-center"
                                                src="https://tecdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(75).webp"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="w-1/2 p-1 md:p-2">
                                            <img
                                                alt="gallery"
                                                className="block h-full w-full rounded-lg object-cover object-center"
                                                src="https://tecdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(77).webp"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </SwiperSlide>
                        <SwiperSlide className="w-full px-2">
                            <div className="h-fit w-auto overflow-hidden opacity-100 container mx-auto ">
                                <div className="-m-1 flex flex-wrap md:-m-2">
                                    <div className="flex w-1/2 flex-wrap">
                                        <div className="w-1/2 p-1 md:p-2">
                                            <img
                                                alt="gallery"
                                                className="block h-full w-full rounded-lg object-cover object-center"
                                                src="https://tecdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(70).webp"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="w-1/2 p-1 md:p-2">
                                            <img
                                                alt="gallery"
                                                className="block h-full w-full rounded-lg object-cover object-center"
                                                src="https://tecdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(72).webp"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="w-full p-1 md:p-2">
                                            <img
                                                alt="gallery"
                                                className="block h-full w-full rounded-lg object-cover object-center"
                                                src="https://tecdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(73).webp"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="flex w-1/2 flex-wrap">
                                        <div className="w-full p-1 md:p-2">
                                            <img
                                                alt="gallery"
                                                className="block h-full w-full rounded-lg object-cover object-center"
                                                src="https://tecdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(74).webp"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="w-1/2 p-1 md:p-2">
                                            <img
                                                alt="gallery"
                                                className="block h-full w-full rounded-lg object-cover object-center"
                                                src="https://tecdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(75).webp"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="w-1/2 p-1 md:p-2">
                                            <img
                                                alt="gallery"
                                                className="block h-full w-full rounded-lg object-cover object-center"
                                                src="https://tecdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(77).webp"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </SwiperSlide>
                        <SwiperSlide className="w-full px-2">
                            <div className="h-fit w-auto overflow-hidden opacity-100 container mx-auto ">
                                <div className="-m-1 flex flex-wrap md:-m-2">
                                    <div className="flex w-1/2 flex-wrap">
                                        <div className="w-1/2 p-1 md:p-2">
                                            <img
                                                alt="gallery"
                                                className="block h-full w-full rounded-lg object-cover object-center"
                                                src="https://tecdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(70).webp"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="w-1/2 p-1 md:p-2">
                                            <img
                                                alt="gallery"
                                                className="block h-full w-full rounded-lg object-cover object-center"
                                                src="https://tecdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(72).webp"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="w-full p-1 md:p-2">
                                            <img
                                                alt="gallery"
                                                className="block h-full w-full rounded-lg object-cover object-center"
                                                src="https://tecdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(73).webp"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="flex w-1/2 flex-wrap">
                                        <div className="w-full p-1 md:p-2">
                                            <img
                                                alt="gallery"
                                                className="block h-full w-full rounded-lg object-cover object-center"
                                                src="https://tecdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(74).webp"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="w-1/2 p-1 md:p-2">
                                            <img
                                                alt="gallery"
                                                className="block h-full w-full rounded-lg object-cover object-center"
                                                src="https://tecdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(75).webp"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="w-1/2 p-1 md:p-2">
                                            <img
                                                alt="gallery"
                                                className="block h-full w-full rounded-lg object-cover object-center"
                                                src="https://tecdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(77).webp"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </SwiperSlide>
                    </Swiper>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

But, the Freemode and the Pagination option don't work, do you know why ? I already try to do this :

import { FreeMode, Pagination } from 'swiper/modules';

```
<Swiper
    spaceBetween={0}
    slidesPerView={1}
    loop={true}
    freeMode={true}
    className="mySwipper my-12"
    pagination={{
      clickable: true,
    }}
    modules={[FreeMode, Pagination]}
  ></Swiper>
```

But I have this errors :
Cannot find module 'swiper/modules' or its corresponding type declarations.
Type '{ children: Element[]; spaceBetween: number; slidesPerView: number; loop: true; freeMode: true; className: string; pagination: { clickable: true; }; modules: any[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Swiper'.

Comment: Do not add "RESOLVE" (or other indicators) to your title. You've posted an answer, when the system allows you to select it as the Accepted Answer, then your question will be properly closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly, I find a solution, we have to use react-id-swiper and it works well !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).